# Old Json Data Doesn't Dissapear After Getting New

Tags: android, json

I am trying get json data from my website through a click button when I fetch data by clicking on the button i receive the data and when I again click on the button it doesn't remove old data which was fetched before here is my code and i am also attaching the screenshot of what i am receiving

```
Button Start;
TextView textView;
RequestQueue requestQueue;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_line);

    Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://www.cricketlinepro.com/newapi.php?method=getRate",(String)null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("info");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String Rate1 = info.getString("Rate1");
                                    String Rate2 = info.getString("Rate2");

                                    textView.append(Rate1 + " " + Rate2 + " \n");

                                }


                            } catch (
                                    JSONException e)

                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    },

                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");

                        }
                    }


            );
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }

    });

}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't disappear from where? If you mean the TextView, it's because you are using `append()` instead of `setText()`

Comment: Ohh crap thanks man you saved my day

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing like it's fetching the data on the button click can it fetch automatically after 0.5 seconds ?

Comment: Look up timer's or JobScheduler's for Android. There's plenty explaining how to do what you want.

Comment: that is another question, post another question for that

Comment: ***After*** attempting it

Answer (score 0):

Use setText to remove data  and for executing code at every 0.5 seconds you can use handler like this.

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // Your code
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //You code
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 500);
```

Using Handler :

```
final Handler mHandler=new Handler();
         Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Your Code
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        };

        mHandler.post(r);
```

Comment: Error:(93, 9) error: mHandler is not public in FragmentActivity; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: Actually i am new to android development can you add this code in my existing code and forward to me that would be so grateful.

Comment: What ide are you using?

Comment: None right now my ide is empty and it gave me a popup to create a new one so i did that but stuck on the same error

Comment: import java.util.Timer

Comment: Thanks a ton mate was able to figure out.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I create a both ways to solve a problem. You can directly insteract with ui in timertask if you do it then it makes app crash. So it is better to use handler if you are interact with ui.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `textView.setText(Rate1 + " " + Rate2 + " \n");`
instead of `textView.append(Rate1 + " " + Rate2 + " \n");` as you are adding the retrievied string to the already existing string present in the Textview